# Unexpected disconnection for users on Chrome with my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, safari, disconnection

Unexpected disconnection occurs for user when they are on google chrome, but it works perfectly fine with safari and on my android smartphone google chrome application, I don't know what to do to resolve this problem.

I tried to manipulate the wp-config file with the instructions :

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.mywebsite.com');
```

I also erase the page cache but nothing changed..

Comment: Disconnection from what? Do you mean a user gets disconnected from your website?

Comment: Actual error messages are always useful.

Comment: I dont have any error log ans yes they are getting disconnected from m'y website but only on the computer's google chrome application